# User not found in the Setting

Tags: login, users

Today, when I turned my laptop on, Ubuntu(20.04) showed me a "Create a user" page instead of a login page.

So I created a new user. Then there was an upgrade notification and I upgraded the Ubuntu. When I tried to run the $whoami command, it showed me the name of my older username. But in setting>Users I cannot see any user and it says "No User Found"

What happened and What is the solution?
Thanks:)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo su
cd /var/lib/AccountsService/users
nano <your user name>
```

change the value for SystemAccount and change it to false
reboot your computer